# Should I remove "$user" from the PostgreSQL search_path?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, configuration

The default setting for `search_path` is `"$user",public`. According to the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH):

> The first element specifies that a schema with the same name as the
>   current user is to be searched. If no such schema exists, the entry is
>   ignored.

At what point will the existence of a $user schema be checked? At the start of the session? Or maybe every time an unqualified object needs to be resolved? If I know that I will only ever be using the "public" schema in a database, would it make sense to remove the "$user" entry?

I realize that this won't make a noticable difference in performance either way, but it might make the setup more explicit... why have something in the `search_path` that's never going to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you

> know that I will only ever be using the "public"

.. it makes perfect sense to remove $user from the `search_path`. You have nothing to gain from it.
I do that in all my clusters anyway.